# laravel get relation table throught another

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've got 3 tables:

```
users: (App\Users)
id|name|email

coupons: (App\Coupons)
id|coupon_code|user_id|discount

orders: (App\Orders)
id|order_id|total|coupon_code
```

I need to connect users with orders, so I can do sort by orders count, I'm trying like this:

orders function belogns to App\User

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Coupons', 'App\Orders', 'coupon', 'coupon_code');
}
```

Is there way to get relation for this tables, so I could use:

```
$users = App\Users->withCount('orders')->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc');
```

I can get correct result by:

```
$coupons = App\Coupons::where('user_id', '=', $this->id);
return App\Orders::whereIn('coupon', $coupons->pluck('coupon_code'));
```

but then I can't do sort on this column

Comment: Is `$user->orders` returning the expected results? Are you sure the relationship is well defined?

Comment: returns empty, when there should be items

Comment: Did you try to modify the model? As it appears in the documentation, you should first place Orders and then Coupons, in the parameters of the hasManyThrough method, and also specify the names of the foreign keys in the tables when they do not comply with the laravel conventions.

Comment: but how could I specify foregin keys?

Comment: in the answer that I put down there is an example, try to place it like this in your model and see if it returns the expected results, according to the documentation this is how the relationship with the method hasManyThrough should be created

Comment: unfortunately still empty

Comment: [Check your queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#listening-for-query-events) to make sure the relationships are OK.

Answer (score -1):

For how you have the tables in the description the way to get the relationship should be the following:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
                'App\Orders',
                'App\Coupons',
                'user_id', // Foreign key on Coupons table...
                'coupon_code', // Foreign key on Orders table...
                'id', // Local key on Users table...
                'coupon_code' // Local key on Coupons table...
            );
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: He is trying to order users by orders count.

Comment: If he makes the corrections in the model he should be able to use the code he has in the description, $users = App\Users->withCount('orders')->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc');, or am I wrong? @Camilo